# LaunchUriAsync does not navigate to the correct uri

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I need to navigate to an internet page within my metro application. 
My url is (sample) 'http://www.foo.com/#/foo'. 
The issue is that LaunchUriAsync cut the url to 'http://www.foo.com'.

```
try
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(item.UriCode); 
    await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    //TODO
}
```

Where am I wrong ?
Regards.

Update :

I precise that uri = http://www.foo.com/#/foo.
So the issue comes from LaunchUriAsync .

Comment: even I am facing this problem. I am trying to open a url with external browser but it neglects the `#fragment` if the browser is not IE by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with the same code just hardcoding the uri that you mentioned 
Please check the code below :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.foo.com/#/foo");
            await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //TODO
        }
    }
```

The output is shown below

[image: Launcher Test with respective URL]

i think there's some other problem.
May be with the `item.UriCode` line please check .

Comment: Thank for your reply. But hard coding wouldn't change this issue. item.UriCode has the right value.

Comment: the sample works even without being hard coded, and the address bar seems to reflect the correct URL. Do you have a sample of a real URL with this format that we can try.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is difficult to diagnose what is actually wrong from your example.

It appears you are trying to navigate to an anchor within a web page, but doing it with incorrect syntax / pointing to a non-existent anchor.  However, your example linked page doesn't seem to contain a navigable anchor.

Assuming that this is actually what you are trying to achieve, try the following example, and you will see that navigation works as expected

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.hypergurl.com/anchors.html#bottom"));
```

If this isn't what you are trying to achieve, I would suggest that the presence of the `#` character in the URI is being interpretted as an anchor reference by IE and that's why you aren't getting the result you require.

Comment: i'm trying to navigate to an flash website which accept navigation like http://www.foo.com/#/menu. But you are right # seems to be the problème.

Comment: Shouldn't the slash after the `#` either be omitted or encoded?  foo.com/#menu

Comment: No the right url is http://www.foo.com/#/menu. It's working. So the url isn't the issue.